# How to custom meta_query to new meta_query

Tags: wordpress

by default WP_Query use

```
$the_query = new WP_Query([
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'name',
            'value' => '%jo%',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'age',
            'value' => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ]

    ]
]);
```

where the meta_query will call the class WP_Meta_Query in which the wp_postmeta table is specified.

I created 1 new table named wp_postmeta_custom . Example code below

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta_custom` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now I wrote a function to add, edit, delete data in a table wp_postmeta_custom is done, but it still lacks a way to connect to WP_Query like meta_query.

I want to run the new table together with the old one like this.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query([
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'name',
            'value' => '%jo%',
            'compare' => '=',
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'age',
            'value' => array( 3, 4 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ]

    ],
    'custommeta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'otherdata',
            'value' => '%jo%',
            'compare' => '=',
        ]

    ]
]);
```